# function and variable execution precedence

Tags: php, function, variables, operator-precedence

I tried to print a simple variable concatenated with a function call, and this is what I got!

```
 <?php 
 $hello = "Hello ";
 function test(){
   echo "This is a function!! ";
 }
 echo $hello.test();
 ?>
```

Here the echo prints the variable hello concatenated by the function call, so that should make the output `Hello This is a function!!`, instead the output is `This is a function!! Hello`.

- How does this work and can someone explain this behaviour?

Comment: Because you `echo`ed the string, rather than `return` it.

Comment: Since I am using concatenation operator here, and what echo should essentially do is print $hello and concatenate the function output to $hello right?

Comment: Try putting a space on either side of the period

Comment: How does it make a difference? The output is still the same!

Comment: Sorry you're right I don't know what I'm talking about :) You need to return the string rather than echo it in `test()`  as already pointed out.

Comment: @RohitPujar TBH, I don't know why that is and I've spent some time trying to find out "why" that is on PHP.net. Good (interesting) question though. Let's see if anyone else will pick up on the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

test() is a void function (it returns nothing) so there is no string for echo to immediately echo and the precedence of the function call is higher than the dot so will be evaluated first and does it's own echo before getting back to do the string join.

> return "This is a function!! ";

.. will work with your original dot joined format (as others have pointed out).

Alternatively, changing the echo line to:

> echo $hello, test();

.. also works.
$hello is a string and gets echoed, ~then~ test() gets evaluated.

Comment: Interesting answer. I for one could not find any documentation on this behaviour/order of precedence. You wouldn't happen to have a link on that, would you? This would help to clarify/back up your answer and for future visitors to the question/answer.

Comment: @Fred. It turned out to be an interesting and deceptively simple question. I couldn't find direct documentation and maybe should have stated so (thanks for the polite nudge), but I tested all sorts of variants and this appears to be what is actually happening. function gets evaluated before echo produces output, but only in the dot form. We take such a simple language construct for granted but the doc shows echo to have some convoluted rules which have not been deemed bugs. So is this specific to echo or is there a more general application?

Comment: Yes it is an interesting question. Others were submitting answers to "fix" their code, yet what the "real" question was about, was to "explain" its behaviour. I was just curious if you had documentation on it that I wasn't able to find, that's why I "nudged" ;-) Fair enough and I think your explanation is rather a good one. I'll upvote. It would be nice to get one of those PHP.net guys to visit the question. I tried my best at using a good title for their question, including the tags. Time will tell I guess. As for if it's specific to echo, that I couldn't say for certain. *Cheers*

Comment: @Fred. After trying to figure it out from source (too hard) I found [link](http://jpauli.github.io/2015/02/05/zend-vm-executor.html#echo-a-concatenation) which explains the 'precedence' I mentioned earlier is a result of the way the engine works and also explains why the comma version works differently and why it is actually preferred. Interesting that we don't see comma method used much in userland.

Comment: Wow, what a great find! Funny you should mention about the comma. A friend of mine and I were discussing about that earlier today, where he mentioned about the comma. You guys must be on the same wavelength ;-) *Tip of my hat to you!*